# PHP PDO Class Memory Usage

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks, pdo

I am having a bit of a time here, I'm trying to properly clean up after myself (;)), and show how much memory is being used by my class and methods.

The issues I am having are thus:

1. It seems that after cleaning up, there is more memory used than the last memory check (Pre-Return Memory))

Here is the class, the test page, and the results (and the results online)

CLASS:

```
<?php

class o7thDB {

public $Type =          1;          // What type of database are we connecting to
public $Host =          '';         // The host server we are connecting to
public $Name =          '';         // The name of the database
public $User =          '';         // The user to login with
public $Pass =          '';         // The password to login with
public $Query =         '';         // The query to execute
public $Params =        array();    // An array of parameters to pass to the query for execution
public $ShouldCache =   false;      // Should the results be cached?
public $CacheKey =      '';         // What should we name the key for this cache?
public $Exceptions =    '';         // Returns a string representing the exception that occurred if any
/* Memory Usage Tests */
public $InitialMemory;
public $PreSelectMemory;
public $CreatePDOMemory;
public $PostSelectMemory;
public $PreReturnMemory;

protected $DBHandle;
protected $Cache;

protected function Connect(){
    $this->InitialMemory = memory_get_peak_usage();
    if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
        session_start();
    }
    $dsn = array();
    switch ($this->Type) {
        case 1: // MS SQL 
            $dsn = array("mssql:host=$this->Host;dbname=$this->Name", $this->User, $this->Pass);
            break;
        case 2: // MS SQL Server
            $dsn = array("sqlsrv:server=$this->Host;database=$this->Name", $this->User, $this->Pass);
            break;
        case 3: // MS Access
            $dsn = array("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$this->Name;Uid=$this->User");
            break;
        case 4: // Oracle
            $dsn = array("OCI:dbname=$this->Name;charset=UTF-8", $this->User, $this->Pass);
            break;
        case 5: // Informix
            $dsn = array("informix:DSN=$this->Name", $this->User, $this->Pass);
            break;
        case 6: // Firebird
            $dsn = array("firebird:dbname=$this->Host:$this->Name", $this->User, $this->Pass);
            break;
        case 7: // MySQL
            $dsn = array("mysql:host=$this->Host;dbname=$this->Name", $this->User, $this->Pass);
            break;
        case 8: // SQLLite
            $dsn = array("sqlite:$this->Host");
            break;
        default: // MySQL
            $dsn = array("mysql:host=$this->Host;dbname=$this->Name", $this->User, $this->Pass);
            break;
    }
    try{
        $this->DBHandle = new PDO($dsn[0], $dsn[1], $dsn[2]);
        $this->DBHandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
        $this->DBHandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->CreatePDOMemory = memory_get_peak_usage();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->Exceptions = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// Destroying Everything
public function __destruct(){
    unset($this->DBHandle, $this->Cache, $this->Type, $this->Host, $this->Name, $this->User, $this->Pass, 
            $this->Query, $this->Params, $this->ShouldCache, $this->CacheKey, $this->Exceptions);
}

// Executes a query against the database, returns boolean success
public function Execute(){

}

// Executes a select statement against the database, returns an associative array
public function Select(){
    $this->Connect();
    $this->PreSelectMemory = memory_get_peak_usage();
    $stmt = $this->DBHandle->prepare($this->Query);
    $stmt->execute($this->Params);
    $ret = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->PostSelectMemory = memory_get_peak_usage();
    if($this->ShouldCache){         
        $cKey = $this->CacheKey . session_id();
        if(isset($this->Cache[$cKey])){
            $this->PreReturnMemory = memory_get_peak_usage();
            return $this->Cache[$cKey];
        }else{
            $this->PreReturnMemory = memory_get_peak_usage();
            $this->Cache[$cKey] = $ret;
            return $ret;
        }
    }else{
        $this->PreReturnMemory = memory_get_peak_usage();
        return $ret;
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    unset($stmt, $ret); 
}

}
?>
```

TEST PAGE:

```
<?php

    // Show All Errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Database/o7th.db.class.php');

    // Time the Execution
    $mtime = microtime(); 
    $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
    $starttime = $mtime; 

    $db = new o7thDB();
    $db->Type = 7;
    $db->Host = 'localhost';
    $db->Name = 'mydb';
    $db->User = 'myun';
    $db->Pass = 'mypw'; 
    $db->Query = "Select * From `modx_session` Where `data` Like ? Or `id` Like ?";
    $db->ShouldCache = true;
    $db->CacheKey = 'a';
    $db->Params = array('%a%', '%Welcome%');
    $ret = $db->Select();   
    $rCt = count($ret);
    echo $rCt . ': Records Returned<br />'; 
    echo $db->Exceptions;
    unset($ret);

    echo $db->InitialMemory . ': Initial Memory<br />';
    echo $db->CreatePDOMemory . ': Create PDO Memory<br />';
    echo $db->PreSelectMemory . ': Pre-Select Memory<br />';
    echo $db->PostSelectMemory . ': Post-Select Memory<br />';
    echo $db->PreReturnMemory . ': Pre-Return Memory<br />';
    unset($db);

    echo memory_get_peak_usage() .': After all is said and done!<br />';

    echo '<hr />';

    $mtime = microtime(); 
    $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
    $endtime = $mtime; 
    $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime); 

    echo "This page was created in ".$totaltime." seconds"; 

?>
```

TEST PAGE RESULTS:

```
21168: Records Returned
288016: Initial Memory
288016: Create PDO Memory
288016: Pre-Select Memory
19209456: Post-Select Memory
19209552: Pre-Return Memory
19209768: After all is said and done!
This page was created in 0.066221952438354 seconds
```

So, my question is, why is it that the code uses up more memory, after all is cleaned up?

Comment: This may be a dumb question.. but.. how were you expecting to have a value set for 'PostReturnMemory' when your script is returning (and thus not executing the current code path )?

Comment: ... and when __destruct is called.. isn't the 'this' pointer going to go away? so 'PostDestructMemory' won't actually exist anymore.. will it?

Comment: :)    yeah I figured as much, but as you can see from the code I posted for the test page, I am running the memory check as well...  and it;s still up there in fact more than what is posted for Pre-Return Memory....even after the cleanup happpens

Comment: Yeah, that was one of those DOH! (bang head on table) moments.  My Destruct Memroy instances will never show, nor will the Post-Return..  I'll edit the Q now

Comment: Er... [memory_get_peak_usage()](http://php.net/memory_get_peak_usage) gives the memory **peak**, i.e., that maximum allocated by the script. Do results change if you use [memory_get_usage()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP process do not release memory that has been freed. By freeing memory in the PHP script you just make it available for the use by the very same process. But whole process always possess all the memory it allocated during it's runtime.

That's why cleaning after yourself is not necessary in PHP - you can't return it to the system during script runtime anyway, yet whole runtime takes only fraction of second - so, there is just no point to bother.

By the way, your class looks too err... imaginary one.
Frankly, it's intended to solve imaginary problems, not real ones. Like connection to all the possible databases. And at the same time it lacks really important things.

And session-based caching mechanism looks just awful. It will indeed pollute your memory with **lots** of useless data.

- Say, there are 10 pages on your site, and every one of them will hold the cached data for all other pages.
- Say, there will be 10 users browsing your site at a time - so, you will have 10 replicas of the same data stored in 10 different files.

With all these numerous **duplicated** "caches" **consuming the very memory you are too concerned of.**

As a result, the effect will be contrary - instead of speeding up your site this cache will actually make it slow and bloated.

That's why it is said: ***"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"***